# Can unlicensed real estate agent sign a lease in Texas?

Tags: residential-lease, contract-law, rental-property

I signed a contract with a apartment complex with 3 months and this agent misinformed me on many things and now I want to get released out of my contract. There was a typo on pre-populated contract he fixed the contract and signed it. Is it valid to sign a rental agreement with unlicensed person?

Comment: There are two separate questions here: can an unlicensed agent sign a contract, and does that make the contract invalid. They are separate questions; the first is likely on-topic, but if you want to know whether you can get out of the contract you should see a lawyer. Even if it's illegal for the person to do what he did without a license doesn't necessarily mean a court will invalidate a contract entered into willingly.

Comment: Also, what relationship does the "agent" have with the property owner?

Comment: He is an assistant working at the leasing office. He is showing apartments etc. I told this person my end date and he did not take action. He claims that the put a notification to my door 3 days after I sign the lease but I never received this. It was 3 month lease. Now, they are asking 60 day notice from me and extending my lease automatically. When I inform community director about this issue she told me that he is not licensed and my talk with him does not effect my contract. But he is eligible to sign the contract?

Comment: What connection does the leasing office have with the property owner? Was the guy who signed the contract an employee of the property owner (i.e. not an independent contractor, not an employee of a subsidiary company)?

Comment: He is an employee of realty trust and on the contract it says Owner's Representative.

Comment: @JoeZappotoni, you have to look at what exactly your contract says.  most of them are very explicit that any promises that are not outlined in the contract are void and null.  you can't really do much about signing a contract with wrong dates, and then claiming you were misinformed.  if, however, the agent you speak of, did make a correction to the contract, prior to you signing it, and he did sign it both in the back, and initial it on the front where the change was made, then such change should be part of the contract, too.

Comment: Why exactly was this question closed as off-topic?  It should have been closed as ambiguous, and corrected to include more details.  I think it might be an interesting question, once all facts are stated.  @JoeZappotoni, please edit the question, and ping me to vote to have it re-open.